# FFmpeg contact with filter on audio and video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have this working `ffmpeg` command and I need to add an `xfade` filter

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "concat:list.txt" -i "music.mp3" \
  -filter_complex "[1]volume=0.1[1a];[0:a][1a]amix" \
  -c:v copy -c:a aac -q:a 4 -r 25 "output.mp4"
```

I tried to add the command :

```
xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=5
```

in the `filter_complex`.

The code that give me the error is

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "concat:list.txt" -i "music.mp3" \
  -filter_complex "[1]volume=0.1[1a];[0:a][1a]amix[2];[2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=5" \
  -c:v copy -c:a aac -q:a 4 -r 25 "output.mp4"
```

this is the error:

```
[Parsed_amix_1 @ 0000026f70206e00] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_amix_1' filter output pad 0 (audio) and the 'Parsed_xfade_2' filter input pad 0 (video)
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000026f70208c80] Cannot create the link amix:0 -> xfade:0
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

the file list.txt contains:

```
file '016698.mp4'
file '15128.mp4'
file '216749.mp4'
file '36680.mp4'
file '416700.mp4'
```

I tried in different ways but I can't find a way to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: What's the error? (please add to your question)

Comment: You need to include the (example) content of the `list.txt` file and also spell out the full modified filtergraph with `xfade`. Please edit the post accordingly

Comment: ok the error is [Parsed_amix_1 @ 0000026f70206e00] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_amix_1' filter output pad 0 (audio) and the 'Parsed_xfade_2' filter input pad 0 (video)
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000026f70208c80] Cannot create the link amix:0 -> xfade:0
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you are using both `amix` and `xfade`. `xfade` needs 2 inputs but you are specifying only 1 the output of `amix`. Do you really need both filters?

Comment: @kesh yes, one filter is to mix and level the audio, the other filter would be for crossfade the videos in list.txt